# Getting downloadable link to a file in EC2 Windows Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS EC2 Windows Server Instance with files on its local drive. I would like to provide a downloadable link (with/without authentication) to other users in the group. Is this possible?

Comment: Better use s3 to store your files, it'll be easy to get and share files with link.

Comment: Does EC2 Windows Server has S3 attached by default?

Comment: Basically EC2 is for computing, so you will have to configure it seperately